# Make a request for each id or a request filtering by ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, performance, httprequest

I have a performance question.

What would be better?

make a request to the backend for each id:

`Promise.all(http://.../1, http://.../2)`

**OR**

make a request to backend filtering by id:

`http://.../id[$in]=1&id[$in]=2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second request is the preferred method if this is for a `GET` request. You can implement pagination as well, so you only get the first `x` items returned, `http://.../resource?limit=1000` for example. Plus, we don't always know how IDs are implemented in the API so the first method would likely be a very erroneous approach. We want the server to tell us the IDs then use these for `post, put and delete` methods.

HTTP has a lot of performance overhead (such as request headers etc.) So generally, `Promise.all` should be avoided if possible.